# jquery compare arrays $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare 2 arrays. One is taken from DOM, generated by **.split(" ")**, the other I would like to be retrived by **$.get** call.

All is working fine if I test the **dictionary** array manually. Example:

```
  // var dictionary = ["in", "the"]; // <- this one works
  var dictionary = $.getJSON('job/dictionary/en');
  $(this).keyup(function() {
      var words = $(this)
                    .text()
                    .split(" "),
          words_final = [],
          i = 0;
        jQuery.grep(words, function(word) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(word, dictionary) == -1) words_final.push(word);
            i++;
        });
    });
```

Response from this URL is *Content-Type: application/json* with response body:

```
[
   "in",
   "the"
]
```

Apparently... then I try to run **$.getJSON('job/dictionary/en')** in chrome dev tools, I get an object back with responseText: *"["in","the"]"*

I've tried with **$.get()** as well with the same result.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You must defer using the response from the JSON call until the call has actually completed; the JavaScript program doesn't wait for the response. Use [`Deferred`s](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred) or the [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) handler, and put your code in there instead.

Comment: @dystroy, I'd like to close this as a duplicate but I consider that question you want to close it against is badly formatted and explained. I'll try to look for a better one among the thousand of possibilities

Comment: @Bergi, perfect indeed. I mark the question as solved.